# Economizing On Space In Arrays Using Static Variables

Tags: java, memory-management

I am working with some relatively large arrays of instances of a single data structure.   Each instance consists of about a half a dozen fields.   The arrays take up a lot of space and I'm finding that my development environment dies even when running with a vm using 7 gigabytes of heap space.    Although I can move to a larger machine, I am also exploring ways I could economize on space without taking an enormous hit in performance.    On inspection of the data I've noticed a great deal of redundancy in the data.    For about 80 percent of the data, four of the six fields have identical values.

This gave me the idea, that I can segregate these instances that have redundant information and put them in a specialized form of the data structure (an extension of the original data structure) with static fields for the four fields that contain the identical information.    My assumption is that the static fields will only be instantiated in memory once and so even though this information is shared by say 100K objects, these fields take up the same memory as a they would if only one data structure was instantiated.   I therefore should be able to realize a significant memory savings.

Is this a correct assumption?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: It's hard to say with any confidence without knowing your data structure and how you are populating it. It doesn't seem that declaring the data static or not is really relevant. The important thing is to share the repetitive data.

Comment: If you don't need instant access on your arrays, you can improve the performance using a `LinkedList`. Another solution will be using a pool of similar object instances and not static fields, remember that `static` belongs to the class, not to the instance.

Comment: Another possible issue is that in the future if you need a field with a different value, you cannot coz uve made it static

Comment: Yes.   But if I use a special class with static values for the repetitive data, wouldn't I dramatically reduce memory usage?   I'm not concerned with having to change values for this information.   When I read the information in, if it is not equal to the repetitive information, I would just use the original class.

Comment: @Elliott It depends on *what* the repetitive values are, among other things. Although from the description it sounds like the desire is to create some sort of object with "fall through" access to a "template" object? (Static fields are the extreme form of this; there is not even a variable/"slot" in the instance objects for values to be put!)

Comment: Please post samples of the arrays/data/types as this will greatly change which approach(es) are viable. Also, don't forget about "disk based" data-structures, which may be another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your specific datastructure and a possible algorithm to buid a flyweight, but I would suggest one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

The pattern is quite near to the solution you are thinking about, and gives you a good seperation of "how to get the data."

Answer (score 0):

How about maintaining the fields that are redundant in a map and just have references to those values in arrays. Could save space by reducing size of individual data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HashMap for your storage. That's the way to fast find equal object.
You need to think how define hashCode function of your objects.